# How to change Youtube video play quality using Javascript in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, youtube

I find the youtube page source has a line about the available video play qualities as follows:

```
ytl.qualityLevels = ["highres", "hd2880", "hd2160", "hd1440", "hd1080", "hd720", "large", "medium", "small", "tiny"];
```

How can I change the video play quality to `hd720` using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an extension doing what I try to do: to play youtube video at hd.

Auto High Quality for YouTube™